# Detecting Chinese Characters in HTML

Tags: character-encoding

useful Link to understand Encoding 
http://kunststube.net/encoding/ - shared by @deceze

I'm trying to detect for the chinese character but cant. When i try echo , i get this
"´Ë±¦±´ÒÑÏÂ¼Ü". I don't need to display it, just need to detect the characters on the html page.

```
//Set the post parameters
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://bit.ly/1y');
    //execute new request
    $htmlcode = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if (stripos($htmlcode, "已下架") !== false) {
    echo "True";
}else{
  echo "Fail";
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page is encoded as GBK. You probably save your source as UTF-8, so `"已下架"` is UTF-8 encoded. Therefore `stripos` will not match, since it just compares bytes and is not encoding aware.

Either convert `$htmlcode` to the encoding of your file or convert `"已下架"` to the encoding of `$htmlcode` to perform string matching. Use `mb_convert_encoding` or `iconv`.

Comment: Like this ? iconv('GBK', 'GBK//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $html);

Comment: No, like `iconv('GBK', 'UTF-8', $html)`. You need to make both strings the same encoding, not convert from GBK to GBK.

Comment: Typo there , sorry. Anyway i tried that can it translated to another kind of chinese. Not that one i see in default :\ i will try compare the "different" type of character"

Comment: "Different kind of Chinese" may just be a difference in **fonts** for traditional/simplified and it's just a display problem; the characters are *probably* fine.

Comment: I looked at the page's HTTP headers.